# Ordering returned elements from a .each() call using a .data()

Tags: jquery, sorting, each

I have a html list with various values attached to each `<li>`.

Can I order the elements based on an associated `.data()` value?

This is so I can create a summary panel with entries sorted by `.data('DataValueX')`.

Just to clarify I don't need to sort the original elements just use data from them to create a new summary panel.

Comment: can u show a simple demo of what you cave in a fiddle and explain better here what u do actually want?

Comment: Please see the answer below and comments - He beat me to it! Any ideas on efficiency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript has a native method called [.sort(sort_function)](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp) that you can use to sort any array.  In this case, you have a jQuery object collection which has an array stack of elements.

Check my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qBBEC/) for a demo of it in action.

```
$(function() {
    var myArray = $('li').get();  

    myArray.sort(function(x,y) {
        return $(x).data('color') > $(y).data('color') ? 1 : -1;
    });

    $('ul').empty().append(myArray);
});
```

Comment: Are there any alternatives to this approach? My list could be up to 400 <li> elements

Comment: .data() calls shouldn't be expensive after the first one.  On the first call, it will pull the data- attribute from the element and store them in jQuery's central cache.  If you wanted to speed it up further (for minimal gains) then you could cache them to variables yourself.  I don't recommend it though.